# Copy to clipboard and send keycode

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, keycode

The function from my Softphone (VoIP Phone on my PC) is, when I copy a phone number in clipboard and then I press "Pause" (German Keyboard), the softphone dials the number. I have created which help from some code examples in internet a copy function, which copied from a field in my database the phone number in the clipboard, when I press a button. It works perfectly. Now I wish to dials the number immediately and therefore it is necessary, the button do not copy the number only, but rather simulated the key press "Pause" after the copy.

Unfortunately my knowledge in PHP is ok, but in JavaScript it is very very bad. And therefore my request is for help me in this case.

Thank you very much in advance

Here is my script:

```
// in $Mobil01 is the phone number
]
<button class=copy-button id=buttonM01><i class=fa fa-copy style=font-size: 20px;></i></button>

<script>

    var telefonM01 = document.getElementById("telefonM01")

    var buttonM01 = document.getElementById("buttonM01"); 
                            

    buttonM01.addEventListener("click", function (eventM01) { 
        eventM01.preventDefault(); 
        telefonM01.select(); 
        document.execCommand("copy");

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Do you need to get rid of non-digit characters in the string?

Answer (score 0):

The `select` event occurs only when a text is selected (marked) in a text area or a text field. So, for working with this you will have to set the element with the id `telefonM01` as some `input` or `textarea` element.

An alternate way of copying text is to attach the text with the button to copy.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But my code works completely perfect. I press one button on my website with leftklick on my mouse and it marked and copiend the number from the input field before. The number is also in the clipboard. And now I must press the "Pause" key on my keyboard. But I wish the button which I have with mouse klick activated send after copying the keycode for the keyboard "Pause" additonal. So I must only make one klick on my mouse and the number was dialing.